# Populate drop down list with iEnumerable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable

How can I populate a drop down list within a repeater for the iEnumerable participants?

```
    Dim ac = pl.pages _
        .Where(Function(p) p.urlName = "2012Basketball" And p.organization.urlName = "CopleyHS") _
        .SelectMany(Function(p) p.actions) _
        .GroupBy(Function(s) s.eventId) _
        .[Select](Function(g) New With { _
          Key .EventId = g.Key, _
          Key .EventName = g.FirstOrDefault().event.name, _
          Key .Actions = g.[Select](Function(s) New With { _
            Key .ActionId = s.id, _
            Key .ActionName = s.name, _
            Key .Participants = s.event.participants.[Select](Function(k) New With { _
                Key .ParticipantName = k.name, _
                Key .ParticipantId = k.id _
            }) _
          }) _
       })

    rep_Events.DataSource = ac
    rep_Events.DataBind()
```

.aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_Events" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <b><%#Eval("EventName")%></b>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rep_Actions" runat="server" Datasource='<%#Eval("Actions") %>'>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <blockquote>
                    <%#Eval("ActionName")%> <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_participants" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Participants") %>' DataTextField='<%# Eval("ParticipantName") %>' DataValueField='<%#Eval("ParticipantId")%>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </blockquote>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The error occurs at asp:DrowDownList, stating that VB$AnonymousType_1 does not contain a property with the name ParticipantName.

```
DataBinding: 'VB$AnonymousType_1`3[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[VB$AnonymousType_2`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], App_Web_2earclkn, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'ParticipantName'.
```

I have attempted to convert the participants with .ToList, and .AsEnumerable, but still getting errors with that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this falls as the second list, Actions doesn't have ParticipantName property. The property is within items of the third list. So you could change the code as follows:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_participants" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Participants") %>' DataTextField="ParticipantName" DataValueField="ParticipantId">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Hope that helps.